# connecting domain name to nginx server

Tags: nginx

I'm having a lot of problems to connect a domain name with an nginx server.

over `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` I have a file called rsmweb:

```
server {
       # this is only 1 of the many configs I've tried..

       listen         80;
       server_name    rsm.website;
       return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {

        listen 443 ssl spdy;
        server_name rsm.website;
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

..etc
```

and I created a symbolic link to `/etc/nginix/sites-enabled/default`

When I used a similar configuration with a localhost it worked, but now I'm trying to use my domain name and I'm really stuck.

In some tries, when I replace the following code with my ip, I can connect by using my ip instead of my domain name. The thing that I can not understand is that if my domain name points to my ip, why it doesn't works?

My domain name is configured like this:

```
  HOST NAME     IP ADDRESS/ URL     RECORD TYPE     MX PREF     TTL 
    @        82.216.93.120          A (Address)        n/a      1800
    www      82.216.93.120          A (Address)        n/a      1800
```

after some reading, I thought that I needed to add my ip/domain over `/etc/hosts`

```
82.216.93.120 rsm.website
```

But I found in a blog that if the domain name points to the ip, it is not necessary to do that...

I'm really confused and stuck, thanks for any help!

Comment: Whatever you did, it appears to have (half) worked... I'm now seeing `http://rsm.website/` redirect to `https://rsm.website/`, which then fails to connect (firewall problem, presumably)

Comment: @rsm per Michael, you gotta fix your IP first (second octet).

Comment: I don't know why but I told my self that it was good pasting my real ip? But the ip of the file is ok! 82.216.93.120, Il correct them from the post

Comment: @rsm http://pastebin.com/nKnLqUSK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an AAAA record with an IPv4 address, that's not going to work :) Use A-records and you'll be fine.

Also add some vhost-specific logging to nginx to see if any requests make it there, and check the server's listening programs with `netstat -plant` to figure out if nginx is the one listening on port 80 and 443.

Comment: I thought that too! I tried with AAAA because in some blogs I found the line `listen [::]:80 rsm.website ipv6only=on;`. Right now I'm running with A-records, but I have the same problem

Comment: I don't know where the OP got that from, but the live config (yes, the site really *is* called `rsm.website`, damn these new-fangled gTLDs) shows that it's really an A record with that IP on it, and no AAAA records in sight.

Comment: @womble "yes, the site really is called rsm.website" Thats funny! an `.com` or `.org` was too expensive for me. At least I didn't bought `.xyx` at 1€!

Comment: In that case, let's to trough the chain: 

(1) Configure access logging, 
(2) Check the access logs, 
(3) Do a `sudo netstat -plant` on the server. 

You should be able to see: a)If any connections reach nginx and 
b) If nginx is the one listening on port 80

Comment: @rsm we get a lot of people who "obfuscate" their questions, removing the real domain/IP and putting in placeholders; there's been a bunch of times people have really used something in `.website` as their example; until recently, that would have been an obvious obfuscation... now, though, it's a real thing!

Answer (score 0):

In your DNS Record:
The IP address is a ipv4 adress, but the record type is set to AAAA (used specifically for ipv6 adresses). Can you change the record type to A?
I also have not seen an @ record before, therefore I would work with the www entry first. You should add it to the server_name in nginx (`server_name rsm.website www.rsm.website;`) however.
Usually you do not have to set an entry into /etc/hosts.

Comment: DNS isn't the problem; rsm.website shows an `A` record of `82.216.93.120`.

Comment: @womble It _was_ the problem. He seems to have fixed it.

Comment: No, I don't think it was.  My first DNS response was gotten at `Tue Aug 11 11:09:50 AEST 2015` and showed an `A` record of `82.216.93.120` then, and the site was misbehaving some time after that.  I'm pretty sure it was just an nginx misconfig which the OP has now fixed.